# How to rename rewarded amount to wallet amount in checkout_index_index.xml overriding module will

Tags: magento2

[Rename Rewarded Amount to Wallet Amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzLKA.png)

Check Image -

Comment: Rename Rewarded Amount to Wallet Amount link with image

Comment: <item name="reward_amount" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Webkul_RewardSystem/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/rewardamount</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Rewarded Amount</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>